# Fastest MPC playback settings for slow copmuters

Tags: netbook, media-player-classic

I'm having a hard time finding the best settings for Media Player Classic so that it could play videos on my weak netbook without stuttering so badly. I tried several recommended ways to reduce the lagging:

- Disabling subtitles − this helps a bit in general and a lot if there are colorful subtitles (anime);
- Selecting *Enhanced Video Renderer (Custom presenter)* with *D3D Fullscreen* enabled − small improvement in fullscreen, but introduces inconvenience of no visible controls;
- Selecting *Overlay Mixer Renderer* − great improvement in performance, but scaling is very low quality;

What are the other options to reduce choppiness of video on weak computers?

Comment: how weak a computer? What's the bottleneck? (task manager should give you a clue). What version of windows? What resolution is the screen and what resolution are the videos?

Comment: Windows 7, Asus EEEpc 1101ha, 1366x768. Bottleneck seems to be resolution when downscaling from FullHD, and perhaps average bitrate is sometimes too high.